# Java web service externalization

Tags: java, externalizing

I am working on a bug for a web service externalization. But I am not sure how to test it. I changed the system locale in windows and also added other languages in IE. But I continue to see the web service in English.

Am I missing something?

Comment: `externalization` or `internationalization` ?

Comment: externalization - for example display the web service in Chinese for a Chinese user.

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by 'web service'? SOAP, RESTful, 'just' a web application, or others?

Comment: @Sairam Sankaran: You should show the relevant parts of your code. Still unclear about what kind of web service we're talking (jee web service is not what I meant), is it about JAX-WS, JAX-RS, etc?

Comment: Btw: you asked this question before, right? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326339/jee-web-service-does-not-display-some-text-in-native-language-internationalizat